# returning results from matplotlib widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

OK so my general problem is that I have a number of datasets, some good, some bad. I want to plot them all then use the CheckButtons widget to choose datasets. I will then average these datasets and they will be returned to be processed further and the next load of data will be called.

Essentially I have 2 graphs callable with `g` and `f` one with two axes (with the data which will be averaged) and the second which shows the average of the currently selected check boxes. I however need to pause in the code until I am happy with the data selection and have been trying to use a matplotlib button to stop and return the current average. Which is where I am struggling

```
    s1,s2=Call.AVERAGE()    #return the average of the checked lines
    av1,=AX1.plot(x,s1)
    av2,=AX1.plot(x,s2)
    def func(label):
        if Call.D[label]==1:    #values with a D[label]==1 are averaged, 0 are ignored
            Call.D[label]=0
        elif Call.D[label]==0:
            Call.D[label]=1
        # every time a check box is changed the new average is calculated and plotted
        s1,s2=Call.AVERAGE()
        av1.set_ydata(s1)
        av2.set_ydata(s2)
        f.canvas.draw()
    def end(event):
        return #from this and outer function...

    ##code for check buttons
    rax = g.add_axes([0.05, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3])
    aq=append(Call.S1.keys(),Call.S2.keys())
    check = CheckButtons(rax, aq, [True]*len(aq))
    check.on_clicked(func)

    ##code for exit/save button
    SAVE = f.add_axes([0.75, 0.02, 0.05, 0.025])
    Sbutton = Button(SAVE, 'save')
    Sbutton.on_clicked(end)

    show()

    return s1,s2 #only return from here after 'save' is clicked
```

I would like to return from this only when I am happy with my tick box selection and have clicked the 'save' button.

I have tried a `while` loop at the end of the code before the return but then the figures appear but with no axes/data/buttons.

Hopefully this makes sense as it is pasted from the middle of my code. It feels like there is a simple solution that I have just missed.

Answer (score 0):

By not having interactive plotting on `ioff()` `show()` acts like a pause until the figure is closed and then in `def end():` I can call `close(f)` and `close(f)` which will then continue with the code returning the current values for s1 and s2.